# Audio Panning using RtAudio

Tags: c++, open-source

I use the RtAudio library.

I would like to implement an audio program where I can control the panning (e.g. shifting the sound from the left channel to the right channel).

In my specific case, I use RtAudio in duplex mode (you can find an example here: [duplex mode](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/duplex.html)). It means that I link the microphone input to the speaker output.

I have searched on the web, but I did not find anything useful. Should I apply a filter on the output buffer? What kind of filter?

Comment: "you can find an example here" - where?

Comment: you are right, now there is the link

Comment: Are you looking for an architecture/design answer? I may be wrong, but I think this would be a better fit for SO, since you're basically asking an implementation question. If you are in front of your IDE your question belongs on SO. If you are in front of a whiteboard your question belongs on Programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pan a sound, you just have to reduce the volume in one channel while increasing it in the other.  But you have to do it in such a way that the overall volume does not change, since a center pan will have two channels producing sound instead of one (full left or full right pan).

More info here: http://logicquicktips.blogspot.com/2006/10/laws-of-pan.html